# AngularJS pass Parameter to Web Api Get

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to pass object parameter from angularJs controller to Web Api 2 Get Method controller.

If i pass object like string it will work but i don't like this solution.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<SearchVenueByParameters_Result> Get(string parameter)
    {
        ObjSearch obj_search = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ObjSearch>(parameter);
```

I would like to try this one :

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<SearchVenueByParameters_Result> Get(ObjSearch obj_search)
```

ObjSearch class :

```
public class ObjSearch {
    public string aAMSID { get; set; }
    public string venueName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public byte? businessSK { get; set; }
    public string subjectAamsCode { get; set; }
    public string subjectDenomination { get; set; }
    public string subjectVatNumber { get; set; }
    public string subjectTaxCode { get; set; } }
```

And in angularjs controller i have :

```
 $scope.objSearch = {
        "aAMSID": "",
        "venueName": "",
        "address": "",
        "businessSK": "",
        "subjectAamsCode": "",
        "subjectDenomination": "",
        "subjectVatNumber": "",
        "subjectTaxCode": ""
        }

$scope.searchVenueByParameters = function () {

    var strObjSearch = angular.toJson($scope.objSearch);
    console.log(strObjSearch);
    $http({
        url: '/api/SearchVenueByParameters_Result/',
        method: 'GET',
        params: { obj_search: strObjSearch }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Venues = data;
        $scope.VenueList = true;
        $scope.showItem = true;

})
   .error(function () {
       $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
   });
    }
```

But in this case i have corrected value printed in console from angularjs controller , but the object passed in the web abi controller is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending complex objects with GET use the [FromUri] attribute which creates your object directly from the URL.

In the client, add the object to the params

```
$http({
    url: '/api/SearchVenueByParameters_Result/',
    method: 'GET',
    params: $scope.objSearch
}).success(function (data) {
    $scope.Venues = data;
    $scope.VenueList = true;
    $scope.showItem = true;
```

The URL will be translated to something like

```
/api/SearchVenueByParameters_Result/?aAMSID=1&venueName=1&address=1&businessSK=1&subjectAamsCode=1&subjectDenomination=1&subjectVatNumber=1&subjectTaxCode=1
```

And in the controller, add the [FromUri] attribute

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<SearchVenueByParameters_Result> Get([FromUri]ObjSearch obj_search)
```

You can read more about the attribute [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: @FrancescoGaleota GET request are design not to have a body. So the [FromBody] will not work with GET.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Post to send objects to WEB API. Replace your code with these

```
 $scope.objSearch = {
        "aAMSID": "",
        "venueName": "",
        "address": "",
        "businessSK": "",
        "subjectAamsCode": "",
        "subjectDenomination": "",
        "subjectVatNumber": "",
        "subjectTaxCode": ""
        }

$scope.searchVenueByParameters = function () {

    var strObjSearch = angular.toJson($scope.objSearch);
    console.log(strObjSearch);
    $http({
        url: '/api/SearchVenueByParameters_Result/',
        method: 'POST',
        params: { obj_search: strObjSearch }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Venues = data;
        $scope.VenueList = true;
        $scope.showItem = true;

})
   .error(function () {
       $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
   });
    }

[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<SearchVenueByParameters_Result> Get(string parameter)
    {
        ObjSearch obj_search = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ObjSearch>(parameter);
```